# Why does echo not echo variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo

```
@echo off

set a[0] = 1
echo %a[0]%
```

When I try to run this, all I get is: "ECHO is off" and not a[0]. When I try to run it with echo on, all it returns is that echo is on. What do I need to change so that it only echoes the value of a[0]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the *white spaces* around the assignment.

Instead of ,

```
set a[0] = 1
```

Use

```
set a[0]=1
```

---

The script would look like .,

```
@echo off

set a[0]=1
echo %a[0]%
```